# Django return JsonResponse and catch data in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Here is my view.
I am returning JsonResponse to ajax request where catching incoming data from my view `'line_product_total': total,` and other contexts

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    cart = self.get_object()
    product_id = request.GET.get('product')
    delete_product = request.GET.get('delete', False)
    product_added = False

    if product_id:
        product_instance = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        amount = request.GET.get('amount', 1)
        try:
            if int(amount) < 1:
                delete_product = True
                return HttpResponse('IntegrityError', delete_product)
        except:
            raise Http404

        cart_product, created = CartProduct.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, product=product_instance)
        if created:
            product_added = True
        if delete_product:
            cart_product.delete()
        else:
            cart_product.amount = amount
            cart_product.save()
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('e_commerce:cart'))
            # return cart_product.cart.get_absolute_url
    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            total = cart_product.line_product_total
        except:
            total = None
        data = \
            {
                'deleted': delete_product,
                'product_added': product_added,
                'line_product_total': total,

             }
        return JsonResponse(data)

    cart = Cart.objects.get(pk=cart.pk)
    return render(request, 'sales/cart.html', {'cart': cart})
```

**js**

```
     $('.type_number').change(function () {

    var product = $(this).next('input[type=hidden]').val();
    var amount = $(this).val();
    var data = {
        product:product,
        amount: amount
    };
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '{% url "e_commerce:cart" %}',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#jquery-message').text('Added' + data.product_added + 'Deleted' + data.deleted);
            if (data.deleted) {
                $('#product-'+product).fadeOut;
            }
            else {
                $('#product-line-total-'+product).text(data.line_product_total);
            }
        },
        error: function(response, error) {
            $('#add-form').submit()
        }
    })
 })
```

**template**

```
<form action="." method="GET">


 <h4 id="product-line-total-{{ product.id }}">{{ product.line_product_total }}</h4>

<input class="type_number" style="text-align: center;margin-left: -50px;" title="" type="number" name="amount" value="{{ product.amount }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ product.product.id }}">
        <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

In short i can not catch variable line_product_total in my ajax 
It just saying `Unresolved variable line_product_total`

But i am sending this variable. What problem?
Guys at least tell me what the problem itself can not do in any way

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Where is it saying that? Show the whole error message.

Comment: no error message but i know certainly reaseon. Data not incoming from my views.py

Comment: how to catch data? Please help me Daniel Roseman

Comment: If that was the problem, why doesn't it error on `data.product_added` or `data.deleted`?

Comment: I don't know but line_product_total jquery says no such variable :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view code doesn't always return a JsonResponse. You should trace both the view execution (adding some `print` or - better - `logging.debug()` before each `return` statement) and also log the effective response you get on the client side instead of blindly assuming you do have a json response with a 200 status.

Also your code is really really bad and even dangereous.

First and most, a GET request **MUST** be idempotent (it must **NOT** change the server's state). Using GET for a requests that creates / updates / delete objects from your database is really looking for trouble.

Then you exception handlers are more than useless, they are harmfull. They catch just *any* exception (including a `SystemExit` !) and silently ignore them, so you will never know when, what, how and why anything goes wrong. Keep your `try` blocks as short as possible (one single statement if possible), only catch exceptions you expect and know how to handle, **log** whatever you catch (with as much contextual infos as you can), and if you really don't know what do with an exception just let it propagate. The user will get a 500 error (yes, shit happens), and (assuming your server and project are correctly  configured) you will get a nice error email with the full traceback etc, so you know something went wrong and have a chance to fix it.

Comment: yeah i checked it from Chrome Network tab view returns data 100% fine but  jquery can not show it. Ok thank you for your advise and answer